# Spring boot CrudRepo Define a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem in spring boot concerning repositories.
I have a service :

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private RoleRepository roleRepository;
}
```

and the repos here :

```
@Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
     User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

When I run the app I get this message :

```
Description:

Field userRepository in com.projectWS.service.UserServiceImpl required a 
bean of type 'com.projectWS.repo.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.projectWS.repo.UserRepository' in your 
configuration.
```

Please help me I'm so desperate...
 this is my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
   }
}
```

Another problem is , `@EnableJpaRepositories` doesn't get recognized !!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't get recognized"? Sounds like maybe you didn't include a dependency on Spring Data JPA. (And prefer constructor injection to field injection whenever practical.)

Comment: I tried every possible dependency in my pom.xml... I don't understand the thing between paranths. Please help me I'ma newbie at this spring thingy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

most likely your `Main` class is defined within a package and your other packages are not getting scanned.

Try annotation your `Main` class with:

```
@ComponentScan("com.projectWS")
```

judging by your error message and assuming that the top of your package level starts at `com.projectWS`

Comment: Thank you !!! I actually did this @ComponentScan("com.projectWS.*") and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Spring expert but I suspect that this can be because of the case of the name of these classes. Just for peace of mind test this please:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Qualifier("userRepository")
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Qualifier("roleRepository")
  @Autowired
  private RoleRepository roleRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not added Spring data for JPA, add the following to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```